# Show $\lim_{n \to -\infty} log(n!)-\sqrt{n} > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, proof-explanation

Show

$$\lim_{n \to -\infty} log(n!)-\sqrt{n} > 0$$

or in other words:

$$\exists N\in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } \forall n>N, log(n!)-\sqrt{n} > 0$$

I tried recursion:

Finding $m'$ s.t. $\sqrt{m'+1}-\sqrt{m'}\leq log(m'+1)$ and $m\geq m' $ s.t. $log(m!)>\sqrt{(m)}$

Therefore we know it is true for $m$ and want to show it is true for $m+1$. We have $log((m+1)!)=log(m+1)+log(m!)$ and $\sqrt{m+1}=(\sqrt{m+1}-\sqrt{m})+\sqrt{m}$.

By condition we set and the property of $m$, we have it true for $m+1$. However, I'm struggling with the process of finding $m'$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your question, what have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Bonnaduck Sorry, just adjusted

Comment: Please also change the title - you have an $n$ which I don't think is supposed to be there.

Comment: The limit is infinite, use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: I think you should clean up the notation. Right now the variables are used inconsistently and the limit point is not a cluster point of the domain.

Comment: @hardmath hey sorry for that, just corrected, changed all x's to n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base case: $\log 6 = \log (3!) > \sqrt 3: 1.792 > 1.732$

$$
\begin{gather}
n \ge 1 \implies \sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt{n} < 1 \\
n > e \implies \log n > 1 > \sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt{n} \\
\log ((n+1)!) - \log (n!) = \log n \implies \log ((n+1)!) - \log (n!) > \sqrt {n+1} - \sqrt{n}
\end{gather}
$$

For $n \ge e$, the LHS increases faster than the RHS as $n$ increases, so the inequality $\log (n!) > \sqrt n$ holds for all $n \ge 3$. Hence $\log (n!) - \sqrt n >0$ for all $n \ge 3$, including as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

For any $n$ you have $\log(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^n\log(i)\geq(n-1)\cdot\log(2)$. Hence,
$$
\log(n!)-\sqrt{n}\geq(n-1)\cdot\log(2)-\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}\cdot\log(2)-1)-\log(2),
$$
where the right-hand side converges to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Hey sorry I can't accept 2 answers, but this is beautiful